# Boot Options for Kickstart install method not recognized

Tags: system-installation, pxe, syslinux, kickstart

I'm successfully installing 12.04 using PXE, as shown below:

```
label ubuntu12.04
    menu label Ubuntu 12.04
    kernel images/ubuntu/12.04-amd64/linux     
    append initrd=images/ubuntu/12.04-amd64/initrd.gz -- ks=http://10.0.1.0/ks.ubuntu
```

This successfully loads the netboot kernel+init, starts up anaconda, and loads my ks.ubuntu file. Inside ks.ubuntu I have the location of installation media:

```
url --url http://10.0.1.0/ubuntu/12.04-amd64/
```

I want this URL in my PXE file, so I can use the `ks.ubuntu` for multiple ubuntu versions. With CentOS, I can append either `method=` or `inst.ks=` (they are aliases) to the boot options. I only have one ks.centos file and use `method=` to setup install media for the selected version. Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize either option, and defaults to using an Internet installation instead of my local mirror. Any thoughts or help would be really great!

Comment: PS - Currently I have one kickstart file per ubuntu installation due to this "limitation" e.g. ks.ubuntu-8, ks.ubuntu-10, ks.ubuntu-12. What I'd like to do is only have one ks.ubuntu file, which is how I'm managing centos. It's much easier to maintain ;-)

Comment: Try this
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility

Comment: Read it multiple times. AFAIK it does not address what I'm asking (unless I switch from Kickstart to Preseed, which I have other reasons for not doing)